# Running an application on a shared NodeJS server

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, shared-hosting

While using my own physical server I did not have any problems, I switched the server to NodeJS supporting shared hosting and started having this problem.

I cannot run the NodeJS application with the "[Application Manager](https://docs.cpanel.net/knowledge-base/web-services/how-to-install-a-node.js-application/)" in the cPanel application. It gives me this output.

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
host : 'localhost',
user : '',
password : '',
database : ''
});

connection.connect(function(){
console.log("MySQL Database is Connected");
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/css'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/js'));

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

app.get('/',function(req,res){

res.render('index.html');

});

app.get('/load',function(req,res){

connection.query("select * from cfg_demos",
function(err,rows,fields){
if(err) throw err;
res.end(JSON.stringify(rows));
});

});

app.listen(3000,function(){
console.log("App is started at PORT 3000");
});
```

Result:

> Incomplete response received from application

What could be the problem with this?

Comment: Some cPanel-like shared hosting plans cannot run nodejs servers because they don't support always-on server processes like nodejs and are built more for a PHP-like model where your script is fired up separately for each incoming request.  Are you 100% sure that your hosting plan supports nodejs server applications?

Comment: Yes. I ran a simple Nodejs application for trial purposes, but unfortunately, I could not run my own project. @jfriend00